# Interfaces and abstract classes in object oriented programming

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

Hi guys,

I decided to dig deep into OOP and have been taking on Design patterns practicing with PHP. I just had a question I would like views on. Interfaces and Abstract classes, which has more advantages? It might be vague but any light shed would be helpful. I can write code to use both and understand each one by concept but I am just wondering which should I be use by default, and why should I be using one over the other. Basically use-case scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Eagletrophy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use both.  To me, interfaces are to describe functionality, and abstract classes are to provide base functionality.

What I mean, is whenever I require an "object type" as a parameter to a method/function, I almost always declare an interface for that purpose.  So my methods have signatures like `foo(BarInterface $bar)`

Whenever I make multiple children from a class (and can share functionality), I make an abstract class that provides the base implementation (and also extends the interface)...

I hope that helps...